# Are "two times" and "twice" interchangeable?

Tags: phrase-usage, adverbs

In English, are *twice* and *two times* interchangeable most of the time?

> I went there twice.
> I went there two times.

Many times, when I use *twice*, they tell me it's *two times*.
When should I use *two times* and when *twice*?

Comment: Can you give some specific examples of when you "use it twice" and "they say to times".  Do you mean you say "... twice ..." and a native speaker of English tells you that "twice" is wrong and you must say "two times"?   To understand this problem I want to see a *specfic example*.

Comment: A [similar question](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/171833/twice-vs-two-times) is asked on our sister site [English Language & Usage](https://english.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

“Twice” is an adverb.

> I went there twice

In the previous sentence, “twice” pertains to the verbal phrase “went there.” “Two times” as a an adverbial phrase is a synonym for “twice.”

> Sally is twice as old as her brother

Here “twice” is an adverb that pertains to the adjective “old.” Here again “two times” can replace “twice.”

“Twice,” however, cannot be used as an adjective and replace “two.”

We say

> May I please have two eggs with bacon on the side

Here “two” pertains to the noun “eggs” and acts as an adjective.

We do not say

> May I have two times eggs

Nor do we say

> May I have twice eggs

It is confusing. In most (probably all) cases, “twice” and “two times” are synonyms, but “twice” is not a synonym for “two.”

Comment: I'm not sure this answers the question.  It is rather unclear, but it seems that the OP is asking for contexts when you must say "two tiems" (which I take to be a typo for "two times" instead of "twice".

Comment: @JamesK You may be right. I interpreted “two tiems” as “two items.” If the poster clarifies the question and my answer turns out to be irrelevant, I shall delete it.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, *twice* and *two times* are mostly interchangeable. You can say you have ***been twice*** to the shops or that you've ***been two times***. Similarly, something can be **[twice as likely](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22twice%20as%20likely%22&tbm=bks&tbs=cdr:1,cd_min:2015,cd_max:2019&lr=lang_en)** to occur or **[two times as likely](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22two%20times%20as%20likely%22&tbm=bks&tbs=cdr:1,cd_min:2017,cd_max:2019&lr=lang_en)**.

Here is an Ngram Google chart showing "two times as likely" (red line) peaking in the 2000s and then dropping quite dramatically in popularity in the following years while the trend for "been two times" (blue line) has been increasing steadily since the 2000s.

[image]

Now, let's compare those results with "been twice" (green line) and "twice as likely" (yellow line). As can be seen in the chart below, the red and blue lines appear to have flatlined compared to their counterparts. The expression "twice as likely" has seen a constant surge since the 1950s peaking at 0.00004500% between 2000 and 2010 whilst the frequency of "two times as likely" only registered a miniscule 0.0000005000%.

[image]

It's safe to say that "twice" is considerably much preferred over "two times" at least where published literature is concerned.

On the other hand, the expression **two-time** is more commonly used in compound nouns, as in two-time+noun. For example, ***The two-time Wimbledon champion** is now out of hospital following surgery on her left hand*. (*The Sun*, 2016), *The former world champion and **two-time Olympic medallist** had hoped to seize the mantle…* ([*The Journal*](https://www.thefreelibrary.com/Brownlee%3A+I+considered+quitting+after+my+bad+year%3B+TRIATHLON.-a0576490738)) ***a two-time winner** of the event* (courtesy of *Lexico*), and ***two-time winners** of the World Cup* (*Wiktionary*). Note that *two-time* should be singular when it is  an attributive.